# Can we save the view added dynamically in LinearLAyout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know that can we save the dynamically added view in any viewgroup or layout???
If yes then how to save??
I am adding an imageview in viewgroup and want to save that whole layout.So is this possible or not???
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: save the dynamically added view means what?, what u want to do.?

Comment: Do you want to save a layout created in code to an xml file? You need to be clearer.

Comment: @ RajaReddy I want to save that whole layout and want to use that as a picture.Is this possible???

Answer (score 0):

i think it might help you..

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
linear.addView(yourviewid)
```